# Can application written in traditional software stack using boost libs be ported into Adaptive AUTOSAR stack

Tags: posix, autosar

I am new to AUTOSAR standards and trying to understand the usage of `POSIX` APIs in Adaptive AUTOSAR stack.

What I could understand that the Functional clusters (services, APIs) in the BSW can access the complete POSIX API set, however adaptive applications are only allowed to use sub-set of POSIX which is PSE51. What does this actually mean?

Is there any way we can reuse some part of the code of my application which is developed using `boost` libraries?

Answer (score 0):

What helps you is that Boost is header-based; no pre-compiled library is needed.

However, there are no universal compilers. Boost was designed to be compiled to desktop OS-es, like Windows or Linux ("traditional" by your words).

Depending on target hardware you will run into more or less compilation problems in Boost source files.

Also, note that Boost is not automotive qualified: just because you fixed the errors and managed to compile, it will not be proven for safety critical use.